# Prometheus QL get the first values from the query result

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I write the query below to get the up time for the microvices.

`base_jvm_uptime_seconds{kubernetes_name="namepspce1"}`

However, it returns multiple values, so the grafana returns "Only queries that return single series/table is supported". I am wondering how can I the first velus from the query result?

I tried `base_jvm_uptime_seconds{kubernetes_name="namepspce1"}[0]`, but it doesn't work..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first inspect the label values of these multiple time series by running the query in Prometheus Graph console.
The you'll need to decide which one you want to display. Random first usually isn't the best idea.
But you can always do `topk(1,query)` if it helps. Just turn the Instant mode on in the Grafana Query editor.